# Select all Id's with column containing all values

Tags: sql-server, select

What is the select query to achieve the following :

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 3 | C |

Expected result : 3

Select All Id's having A and B and C as Value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could aggregate and count the distinct values:

```
select Id
from t
where value in ('A','B','C')
group by id
having Count(distinct value) = 3;
```